# G suite custom fields provide by Google openID client userinfo endpoint

Tags: google-oauth

I would like to ask if it is posible to include in an /userinfo google openId client call, some G suite users custom fields.

The idea is to create a custom schema (https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/Custom-Schemas) for users and add some fields. The standard google userinfo call with scopes email, openid and profile gives this fields:
  "sub"
  "name"
  "given_name"
  "family_name"
  "picture"
  "email"
  "email_verified"
  "locale"
  "hd"

If I add a custom schema for users, are those custom fields in relation with the "profile" scope?, do I have to add a new scope?

Comment: I think you should contact the owner of that system.

Comment: Hello, I have to give a solution to the system owner. My doubt is if there is a relation between G suite custom schemas and scopes in google openid clients

Comment: I doubt google would let you add claims to their oauth token response.  Im not even sure how that would work.

Comment: Yes, that could be right, but I only need to retrieve that data from de openID userinfo endpoint. I do not need the data in the id or access token claims. If i could get it from the userinfo, that would be great.

Comment: For example if you want to use a custom field for your G suite users and you want to use that information in an app that uses openID, this can not be done with the openID client?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up calling the google directory api asking for the fields that I needed from the user.